500 Missing required param "id" in nuxt 3, how solved it?
this is my structure folder
 - pages/
   --companies/
       ----[id]
           --employes/
           --roles/
           --teams/
       ----index.vue
   --index.vue
   --login.vue

My structure folder


when I try to access http://localhost:3000/login, the login page is not open.
I found error

500 Missing required param "id".


What's in login.vue right now? Do you have a middleware? Any specific router configuration? A [repro] is highly welcome.
